# Pattern not working with readonly attributes

Tags: html, forms

I have this form where user need to submit the num of days and it cannot be less than 1. So, I put a pattern there and with read only attribute. 
My question is, why the pattern is not working when I put the readonly attribute? Let say, the numofdays is zero, supposedly when I submit, it will say the pattern is not match. But, when I put the readonly, the pattern is not working and the form is submitted even if the pattern is not correct. Is there any way that I can do this?

**HTML**

```
<form>

<input class="form-control" type="text" name="numofdays" id="id1" value="diffdays"  pattern="[1-9]"  title="No of days should not be less than 1" readonly>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's by design.

> Constraint validation: If the readonly attribute is specified on an
>   input element, the element is barred from constraint validation.

Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-readonly-attribute

Comment: Ooh..Now I get it. Thank you for the explanation! :))